# Label being cut off in TableView Xcode10/Swift 4

Tags: ios, uitableview

When creating a new tableview with a single label, the label is being cut off and I cannot seem to increase the size of the cell to accommodate it.  I would like to just have a fixed vertical size on the cell. I have tried so many different UI settings nothing seems to work and it seems simple.  Here is what it looks like:

[image]

Here is what it looks like in design:

[image]

Comment: post some code please

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options to fix this. I have listed them below.

1. Do not define constant Height constraint for the label. Instead
   control the layout using top and bottom constraints.
2. Define constant height constraint for label and play with
   `Autoshrink` property. It can be set to `Minimum Font Scale` and
   `Minimum Font size`

Answer (score 0):

You should try using `autodimension` for cell size

Answer (score 0):

The solution used was this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.eventCategoryListTableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
}
```

In addition to this code above you have to make sure to set top, bottom, and height constraints for the label.